# How do I make the spacing relative to screen width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm writing code for a website and ran into issue where I need to have relative background to the user's screen width but cannot figure out how do I do it.

I've tried using relative units and media queries as you can see in the code below. I've also tried to use classic container which does work to some extend but as the page gets smaller it hits browser windows borders eventually. The goal is to make a small white space between the end of browser window and the "background-dark-white" that would be relative to user's page width.

```html
<section id="jobs">
    <div class="container-fluid background-dark-white pt-4 pb-3 shortest">
        <div class="container-fluid shorter-inner">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mt-3 mb-0 mx-auto">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="../images/painting.jpg" alt="painting-image" class="card-img-top">
                        <div class="card-body background-dark-white">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-capitalize">painting</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">
                            <h5 class="text-grey font-weight-light pb-3 pt-1">Draw an artwork.</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--End of technology card-->
                <!--Marketing card-->
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mt-3 mb-0 mx-auto card-width-longer">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="../images/engineering.jpg" alt="engineering-image" class="card-img-top">
                        <div class="card-body background-dark-white">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-capitalize">engineering</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">
                            <h5 class="text-grey font-weight-light pb-3 pt-1">Assemble the parts together.</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--End of marketing card-->
                <!--Design card-->
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mt-3 mb-0 mx-auto card-width-longer">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="../images/computing.jpg" alt="computing-image" class="card-img-top">
                        <div class="card-body background-dark-white">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-capitalize">computing</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">
                            <h5 class="text-grey font-weight-light pb-3 pt-1">Write an amazing computer program.</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--End of design card-->
                <!--Product card-->
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mt-3 mb-0 mx-auto card-width-longer">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="../images/advertising.jpg" alt="advertising-image" class="card-img-top">
                        <div class="card-body background-dark-white">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-capitalize">advertising</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">
                            <h5 class="text-grey font-weight-light pt-1">Know advanced advertising tactics.</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--End of product card-->
                <!--Service card-->
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mt-3 mb-0 mx-auto card-width-longer">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="../images/servicing.jpg" alt="servicing-image" class="card-img-top">
                        <div class="card-body background-dark-white">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-capitalize">servicing</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">
                            <h5 class="text-grey font-weight-light pt-1">Provide quality services worldwide.</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--End of service card-->
                <!--Selling card-->
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mt-3 mb-0 mx-auto card-width-longer">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="../images/writing.jpg" alt="writing-image" class="card-img-top">
                        <div class="card-body background-dark-white">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-capitalize">writing</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">
                            <h5 class="text-grey font-weight-light pt-1">Write a book and express yourself.</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--End of selling card-->
                <!--End of the benefits section-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here are all CSS modifications I've made :

```css
.shortest {
  max-width: 100rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 90rem;
}
.shorter-inner {
  max-width: 100rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 76rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .shortest {
    max-width: 100rem;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .shortest {
    max-width: 70rem;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .shortest {
    max-width: 50rem;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .shortest {
    max-width: 40rem;
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Does it have something to do with wrong media queries? Thanks to anyone for helping me out!

Comment: Do you have a screenshot or an image to illustrate what you want? I am not sure I understand the requirements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `rem`, which is relative to the font-size of root element.
`%` is relative to the parent element, so have that in mind.

If you want to get 'screen width size', you can use `vw` (= Vievport Width), which gives you 1% of said vievport width.

---

You can read more here: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

Comment: Yes I've tried using vw but it didn't work at first. I've tested it with some adjustments I've made recently to the code and it did work as planned. Thanks for reminder man so I tried it one more time!